# JAXB unmarshaller with custom interceptor?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Is it possible to "intercept" the unmarshalling process of `JAXB`?

I have an xml reponse that partially should be converted to a different java fields structure:

```
<xml>
  <X_FIELD1></X_FIELD1>
  <X_FIELD2></X_FIELD2>
  ... 
  <X_FIELD11></X_FIELD11>
</xml>
```

In my java class, I'd prefer to unmarshal this to a `List<String>`, instead of 11 `String` fields.

```
public class XmlResponse {
   private String X_FIELD1;
   private String X_FIELD2;
   //...
   private String X_FIELD11;

//   private List<String> xFields;
}
```

But is that possible?

Comment: you can combine similar tags in List not different one.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a custom xml adapter

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlJavaTypeAdapter.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html

apply it on the class level and implement the adapter.